# Using predicate with "begin with", "end with"

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

When using `NSPredicate` with the keywords `BEGINWITH` and `ENDWITH`, my program crashes with the error: `Unable to parse the format string "name BEGINWITH 'j'"`, but the codes have no error.

By the way,any other keywords such as `BETWEEN`, `LIKE`, `IN` function well. Why?

Comment: I believe it's `beginSwith` and `endSwith` (note the S)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means you have a problem with your format string. In this case, it is a simple matter of misspelling the keyword. The correct keywords are `BEGINSWITH` and `ENDSWITH`— note the pluralisation.